# Generating patches for open source, source code in virtualenv site-packages

Tags: python, open-source, virtualenv

I have an open source python library sitting in my virtualenv site-packages. And I noticed a bug in that library and would like to contribute my patches back to the open source project.

The problem is, my virtualenv site-packages is not version controlled by git (obviously, since it was installed via pip) and it's a pain to rename a specific string which is causing the bug (which is located in multiple files, 10+ files) manually and then using diff to generate the patches.

A simpler way - since the project is hosted on github - is actually to place that library under git control, and then make a "pull request" on github.  But I am not sure whether it makes sense or not to be directly managing a git repository inside my virtualenv's site-packages directory. (will that cause problems to pip???)

How would you manage your personal workflow to contribute back to open source projects efficiently in such a scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fork the project on github, clone it to a directory separate from your virtualenv, make the pull request, and install your own fork into the virtualenv by pointing pip at your fork in github.